# How to properly configure Julia portable or standalone

Tags: julia

How to correctly configure [Julia portable or stanalone](https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/winnt/x64/1.5/julia-1.5.0-win64.zip),
For everything to happen from the external storage USB drives: Add, update packages ?
In Julia's helps is there any procedure?

This is what happens to me after running the .bat file.
From the USB flash I still have reference to the installation of Julia in C:
[image: after running the .bat file.]

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to configure your `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`.
This is the place where Julia is installing it's packages and holding pre-compiled codes.

Assume your installation (USB drive) is `D:\` and you unzip Julia to `D:\Julia1.5.0`

```
mkdir D:\JuliaPkg1.5.0
set PATH=D:\Julia1.5.0\bin;%PATH%
set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=D:\JuliaPkg1.5.0
julia
```

Now you are ready to install the packages etc.

Comment: Where or How to edit DEPOT_PATH? in julia>; pkg> ; C:\Users\Xxx>. or D:\ julia-1.5.0-win64\julia-1.5.0\etc\julia\startup.jl

Comment: These are shell (command line) commands. For an example you could create a file myjulia.bat and copy-paste those content or you can run `cmd` and copy paste it to console (assuming you are using Windows which I guess is the case).

Comment: Does this mean that I must run the .bat file every time I use the USB flash on a different PC?
This solution is viable:
[link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/where-or-how-to-edit-depot-path/13501/15)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of
[Przemyslaw Szufel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63421115/8409550) and the  [link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/where-or-how-to-edit-depot-path/13501/15)

The final solution is the following:
File batch windows

```
@echo off
set myDIR=%~d2\SA_Ptbls\julia-1.5.0-win64
if not exist %myDIR% (mkdir %myDIR%)
set PATH=%~d2\SA_Ptbls\julia-1.5.0-win64\julia-1.5.0\bin;%PATH%
set JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=%~d2\SA_Ptbls\julia-1.5.0-win64
julia
```

1. % ~ d2 gives you the current drive letter when connect the USB drive
   to another computer (the drive letters change!!!)
2. if not exist% myDIR% (mkdir% myDIR%) checks if the subdirectory
   exists, if it does not exist it creates it

When executing the batch file, we successfully obtain:
[image: Julia_PortableOk]

And to run the batch file from a shortcut. After creating the shortcut it was configured as shown:
[image: ShortcutJuliaOk]

I did not achieve that in the status bar when executing the batch file the Julia icon was shown; and instead shows the WindowsPowerShell icon:
[image: statusbarJuliaPortable]