# How to update Juia portable or standalone from 1.5.0 to 1.5.1

Tags: julia, updates

I have configured Julia portable or standalone according to the link:[Julia portable or standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63417499/how-to-properly-configure-julia-portable-or-standalone/63421115?noredirect=1#comment112178292_63421115)
But I want to update to the latest version of Julia 1.5.1.
How to proceed?
Should I add all the packages again?
Is there a way to import it to the new version?

Answer (score 0):

Julia does not support version upgrade. It perhaps might work for some packages but you are always risking to running into issues.

Hence you need to delete the `.julia` folder (or set a new `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` location which is configured by system variable) and just reinstall all the packages.

However if you for some reason strongly want to reuse the `.julia` folder you can try:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/a-proper-introduction-on-how-to-update-julia-somewhere-accessible/28166